# New databricks feature: import is not working

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I have uploaded my databricks notebooks to a repo and replace %run sentences with import using the new databrick public available features (Repo integration and python import): https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/07/databricks-repos-is-now-generally-available.html

But its seems its not working

I already activate the repo integration option in the Admin panel but i Get this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'petitions'

For simplicity I moved all python files to the same directory. I get the error in the procesado notebook

[[image: Repo structure1]

Comment: what DBR version is used?

Comment: 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12) In Azure Databricks Service

Comment: Well @AlexOtt seems that I had created the 9.1 cluster but the notebook was running in a old 8,3 cluster. Than You!

Comment: great! yes, this functionality is available starting with 8.4

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use full path to file from repo root:

```
from folders.file import class
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Azure DataBricks and Python Notebooks, you can't import them as modules.

From the documentation:

> If you want to import the notebook as a Python module, **you must edit**
> **the notebook in a code editor** and remove the line # Databricks
> Notebook source. Removing that line converts the notebook to a regular
> Python file.

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos#work-with-python-and-r-modules

Comment: the problem was in the incorrect DBR version